Functionality of new purple, orange and green Duplo train action bricks
From what I can see Duplo train set 10427 will have new purple and light green action bricks. Set 10428 will have new orange, dark green and purple action action bricks.
With the current trains I have seen these action bricks:

Red: Stops the train.
White: Turns the light on/off
Blue: Stops the train for a few seconds and plays a sound
Yellow: Plays a sound
Green: Reverses direction

What will the new colors do? Will the existing trains support the new action bricks?
From Lego.com these are the action bricks shown on 10428:


Looking at the description in the specification for 10428 which states:

They can load the train with cargo, charge the engine or wash the carriages. Each activity is brought to life with lights and sounds when the toy train passes over one of the 5 action bricks.

I imagine that they trigger different sounds from the engine, such as running water, zapping/charging or general clanking, based a little bit on the pictures and that description
Set 10427 also offers:

The 3 action bricks bring play to life, prompting the toy train to make realistic noises as it passes over them, boosting toddlers’ prediction skills as they guess what sound the train will make. They can also use the special customization brick to play their own sounds recorded using the free LEGO® DUPLO® Interactive Trains app, which also lets them drive the train using a portable electronic device.

Again suggesting that the bricks will trigger specific sounds (birds/woodland, etc.) judging by the video on that page, the Red "House" brick acts as a Stop brick.
I expect the older trains might pick up some of the bricks for example this answer from Jan 2024 notes that the sensor was cycling through a series of colours to find a match, so the more recent trains may well do something for some of the colours.

Fully expect a better answer to be provided once these sets are released in Jan, but there wasn't enough room in a comment ;)

I have been wondering why nobody had yet bought one of these just to answer the question, but the train not coming out for another month explains it.  :)

Sadly my expertise with Duplo trains stopped about 12 years once the kids moved on to System. Did still dig it out now and again for visiting relations when they were interested.

It is a new application where the two new Duplo train sets that will be marketed in January are already shown. It is different from the one that already existed. And in theory there are the purple pieces that would allow recording

Hi Ramon and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you please detail what do you base this theory on? You can edit the answer to provide more details. Thanks and play well!

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

A new app for controlling Duplo trains has also been released in December. It says that it is compatible with the old trains, but does not indicate whether they will interact with the new coloured pieces.

Do you have a link, a name of the app or the source of the information?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.duplo.interactivetrains&pli=1
